# python os path join seems to not work correctly between win and OSX OS

Tags: python

I am having a problem with a simple piece of code, which run on both OSX and Windows. I am using  Python 3.7.9.

All I am doing is to chain a path to a filename; I read a directory content, then create the full path to open this file

The path is relative; I run the python script in the same directory where `images_to_rename` is located

```
from os import path, listdir

# Dir where the images are
assets = "images_to_rename"
# create a list of files in that dir
filelist = listdir(assets)

for file in filelist:
    # join path and file name
    joined_name = path.join(assets, file)
    print(joined_name)
```

let's say that the folder has `panorama.png` and `house.png`. When I print on Windows, I get `images_to_rename\\panorama.png`, which is wrong, since it should be `images_to_rename\panorama.png`. Not sure what is the point to use `path.join` if it cannot correctly use the same code on win and OSX.

I can work around by replacing `\\` with `\` with a replace when I call `path.join`, but I was hoping to avoid that using path join. Am I missing something?

Comment: the path is correct in both windows and Mac, it is just the way it is shown, in windows it is shown as \\

Comment: The \\ in the printed value is just Python’s representation of a \ - i.e. there’s nothing wrong. And presumably your code finds the file which is the best confirmation of that.

Comment: I don't see the same behaviour with Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks; so fundamentally it does not matter if there are 2 `//` it does not mater much. I stopped there and didn't execute the rest of the code to open the file when I saw that, but indeed the load code works. Thanks